# How to get cordinates on a Image Control on clicked

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, imagemap

I have an ImageMap on which i want to get the cordinates once user clicks on a particular region. How can this be done. I want to get x,y od every single location wherever user clicks.

Later i want to use this coordinates to draw a hotspot. Can anyone guide me how to go about the same?

Comment: Is this webforms or winforms or WPF?
Take a loot at events and not the clickevents but the mousedownevents

Comment: You don't say "javascript" as one of your tags, so can I confirm that you need to do this from the client?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do so by using an [image submit button](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.image.html).